# Select count of occurrence in date range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a table that looks like:

[image: Table of Attendance]

I'm trying to figure out how to select the number of checked boxes *within a range*.
IE: Select number of checked boxes for Joe between November 27th and December 18th.

I'm really not sure where to start with this, so I don't have much to show for my efforts.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:F=TRUE, "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&B1:F1, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "where Col2 >="&DATEVALUE("2019-11-27")&" 
    and Col2 <="&DATEVALUE("2019-12-18")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: If I wanted to further reduce the results to a scalar for one person, I could remove the group by and add a where statement, correct?

Comment: no, "group by" needs to be present. do it like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:F=TRUE, "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&B1:F1, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "where Col1 = 'Joe' and Col2 >="&DATEVALUE("2019-11-27")&" 
    and Col2 <="&DATEVALUE("2019-12-18")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"))`

Comment: Thank you.  Would you be able to explain the purpose of the ♠ characters?  Also, when I try to invert the selection to FALSE, it appears to break.  Effectively, trying to count the number of FALSE entries appears to work differently.

Comment: I think I realize that the special characters are being used as delimiters to split / transpose the data to a query-able state.

Comment: FALSE should work same. yes special symbols are only for purpose of cutting the string with SPLIT. you can use any symbols you wish they just needs to be unique compared to your dataset